# Right way of assigning JVM parameters in JBOSS eap 7.1

Tags: jboss

Can anyone please tell if the below syntax is correct(specifically double quotes)?Or there should not be any quotes after $JAVA_OPTS at the beginning of  "-XX:+UseG1GC ?

```
 JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:+UseG1GC -Xloggc:/opt/jboss-eap/gc_logs/jvm-gc.log  -XX:+PrintGCDetails   -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC  -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime  -XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any quotes at the beginning of `-XX:+UseG1GC` . Your final `JAVA_OPTS` will be

```
 JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseG1GC -Xloggc:/opt/jboss-eap/gc_logs/jvm-gc.log  -XX:+PrintGCDetails   -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC  -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime  -XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no quotes after $JAVA_OPTS. 
In any case you may check the result in server.log. 
Below is my example from bin/standalone.conf for EAP 6.4

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2000m -Xmx2000m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xloggc:../standalone/log/jboss_%p.gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:-PrintTenuringDistribution  -XX:-PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintReferenceGC"
```